# Passing uint8_t to std::hash<unsigned int> provides random results VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pass-by-reference, inline

std::unorderded_map<X,...>::find() failed due to a "bug" in the hasher. However I'm not sure whether this is a bug in the code or a bug of Visual Studio 2019 compiler. It occurs only if /Ob2 is set as compiler option. The hasher essentially looked like

```
struct X
{
  uint8_t a;
};
struct XHasher
{
  size_t operator()(const X& x) const
  {
    std::hash<unsigned int> hashInt;
    return hashInt(x.a);
  }
}
```

(I omitted other members and parts of the hasher which are not significant here.)
Now the hasher provided different results for same X objects so find() failed.
The fix was to use hash<uint_8> instead of hash< unsigned int >  . So far so good.
However I think conversion from unsigned integers is pretty well defined and the following also works as expected:

```
size_t operator()(const X& x) const
{
  std::hash<unsigned int> hashInt;
  unsigned int tmp = x.a;
  return hashInt(tmp);
}
```

So it looks like either passing uint8_t value as unsigned int&, which is the type of the parameter of std::hash::operator(), is undefined or the compiler creates false code if /Ob2 is set?
The compiler dind't issue any warning here.

Comment: Sounds like you have UB somewhere in your code.  That is indicated that by adding a variable that has no actual purpose, it changes the behavior.  Any way we could get a [mre] of the non-working code?

Comment: If you are running the code several times and noticing different values, this is normal. `std::hash` only guaranties the same output for a given input over the course of a single execution. The same input could give a different output next time you run the program, but it has to always give that output over the course of that run.

Comment: Also getting different behaviour when you set optmization options is a good indication of UB

Comment: @Fancois Gives different results in same process so unordered_map::find() fails although the key is present.

Comment: @john Yes I know that there is UB, sorry, isn't that what I wrote? So my question is what is the reason for UB? What is wrong with the code of the original XHasher?

Comment: @nathan It is difficult to provide a minimal reproducible example since it depends on the complete code structure whether the failure occurs. The problem is passing uint8_t to std::hash<unsigned int>::operator() as I wrote.

Comment: *So may question is what is the reason for UB?* Most lkely it has something to do with the code you wrote.  Without a [mre], we can't tell you which part.  A typical thing to look for is accessing arrays out of bounds.

Comment: @nathan The code I wrote is the XHasher. Looks like you don't see my code examples?

Comment: I've seen your code in your post.  The problem is the code you've posted can't exhibit the behavior you are describing.  It is 100% legal, safe and conforming to pass a `uint8_t` to `std::hash<unsigned int>::operator()`.  That means your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. They encouraged me to look for a different reason, other than the hasher. Looks like the key (which is struct X in my example) of the find() call does not work if it is a (const) reference. But this is probably caused by the code that provides the key. So I will check that. The essential hint was "It is 100% legal, safe and conforming to pass a uint8_t to std::hash<unsigned int>::operator()"